# Formula with non-closing brackets

Tags: equations, lyx

I need to represent formulas similar to this:

[image: target formula]

I have tried to get this with Lyx on Ubuntu but struggled to make "non closing" single brackets.

Do you know either a proper way to code this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\left\{ ... \left| ... \right. ... \right.
```

Use the dot for a non existing delimiter

Comment: Thanks, exactly the tips I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use an environment of the  `cases` family. Here's a suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

    \[ (P)\begin{dcases}
      \max z = 8x_1 + 2x_2 \\
        \text{s.\,c. }\begin{array}{V{2}c}
          x_5 \le 1 \\
        x_2 \le 5 \\
        x_1 + x_2 \le 8 \\
        x_1, x_2 \ge 0
        \end{array}
    \end{dcases} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]